# VBA Bypassing Clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following method to essentially take information from one location to another without using the clipboard.

```
    With "My Named Range"
        "My Location".Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    End With
```

However, the following has been posed to me, suggesting this is in fact slowing my process and taking up more space than necessary

"The "with" statement copies the "with" thing into memory for rapid access, but it basically limits the heavy lifting to 1 copy - when only using it once this actually adds processor actions, rather than net reducing them."

What is the most efficient way to copy a range from one location to another??

Comment: Like RBarryYoung says below one time use is pretty standard, but loops are bad. I tend to use arrays because its not often youre just doing simple "pick up and drop off" behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colleagues probably think that it's faster to to localize the reference, like this:

```
Dim rng as Range
rng = "My Named Range"
"My Location".Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count) = rng.Value
```

Thinking, this is faster because any access to the Excel object model is slow, so only doing whatever's in `"My Named Range"` once is faster than doing it three times.  However, ***this is wrong because this is exactly what the With statement is already doing*** implicitly.  Making it explicit does not make it any faster.

What the above code also makes clear is that you are *not* "just using it once", you are actually using it three times in that one statement.  But even if you were only using it once, the difference is trivial, however, the cost of repeatedly traversing the Excel model to get back the same reference can add up and in a loop, it is not trivial.

The real advantage to using the `With` (or explicit localization as in my example above) is that you can edit it, adding more references without having to add With/localization later, plus many find it easier to read (I do).  So on-balance, the cost of `With` is small, the potential benefit is large (both for performance and readability), so I generally do it as a standard practice.

The real key here is range-array copying like either `With ... =.Value` as you had it, or like `.. = rng.Value` is *always much faster* than copying one cell at a time (and usually faster than using the pastebuffer which copies the whole cell(s), not just the values).

---

I have been asked to clarify my answer WRT "which is actually faster", which is fair because it's complicated the following factors:

1. One of my original premises was wrong:  that explicit localization was different from using the `With`.  In fact they do the same thing and so my example code above has exactly the same performance as OPs original code.
2. The OP quotes critics of the OPs code that have an incorrect premise about that code: That the code was "*using it only once*".  In fact, the OPs code uses the implicitly localized `With` object *three* times.  Because you actually have three references, the `With` is definitely faster.  Even if there was only two references, it would still be definitely faster.
3. I never actually answered the *assumed* question "*What if there's only one reference?*".  Indeed, if there is only *one* reference then localization (whether explicit or using `With`) is *marginally* slower.

So, what do I mean by "*marginally* slower"?  I mean that the cost of an additional object reference storage is small when compared to the very large cost of a reference to the excel object model.  In fact it's like 100x smaller.  That's small enough that it really falls into the category of "coding style & editability" concerns, and *NOT* "performance concerns".

So to summarize the performance impact of using `With` (versus base code that uses explicit Excel model references):

| # of References | Run-Time Impact of WITH |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | -199 |
| 2 | -99 |
| 1 | +1 |

As you can see from this table: *2 or more references*: Definitely faster,  *Only one reference*: Marginally slower.

Comment: I doubt that there is any difference. Assigning the range to a variable creates a named entry into the symbol table (pointing to the range) while the `With` statement would store the reference in some other place (stack?). Speed shouldn't differ in any way. Of course you are right that you should avoid looping, but I think there are > 100 Q&A on SO about that

Comment: @FunThomas Yep, you are right, I should've checked first.

Comment: @FunThomas OK, I have tried to correct my answer.  Let me know if you see any other problems.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - you're answer has been extremely educational. Can i just confirm that using the with statement or the named range as above is infact faster than doing the following; 

```
"My Location".Resize("My Named Range".Rows.Count, "My Named Range".Columns.Count) = "My Named Range".Value 

```

Comment: @Newbie Sorry for the confusion, my initial answer was incorrect as FunThomas pointed out, and since you had already accepted it I could not delete it so I had to edit it to be correct.  I understand that the end result might be confusing.  So what I am saying is:  ... Well it's complicated.  I will try to update my answer to clarify it.

Comment: Ahh i see - my basic understanding was a with statement is the fasted, followed by a named range, followed by explicitly writing the range. But i suspect this understanding is in fact incorrect??

Comment: @Newbie I have added an addendum to my answer that hopefully makes everything clearer and more explicit.  Please let me know if you still have questions.